# Update Trigger isn't updating

Tags: trigger, field-update, update, before-trigger

I'm trying to write an update trigger on custom `orders` object. There is a field `Ship_To__c` in `orders` object which is a text value. Another table `SUBSCR_SYSTEMS__c` holds data `LEGACY_CUST_NUM__c` that is same as `Ship_To__c`. These two fields have no relation.

So I'm updating another field `account__c` in `orders__c` object by querying the same from `SUBSCR_SYSTEMS__c`.

I checked the debug logs, I see that the *before update* event fires off but there is no change in account__c field in orders. What am I doing wrong?

This is what I have tried so far:

```
trigger updateAccountName on orders__c (before insert, before update) {
List<orders__c> ord = new List<orders__c> ();
List<SUBSCR_SYSTEMS__c> partnerAcc =new List<SUBSCR_SYSTEMS__c>();

for(orders__c go: Trigger.new)
{   
 if(go.Ship_To__c==''){        
        partnerAcc=[select Account__c from SUBSCR_SYSTEMS__c where LEGACY_CUST_NUM__c=: go.Ship_To__c];
        go.account__c=partnerAcc[0].Account__c;
        ord.add(go);
   }        
 } 
update ord; 

}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Hi @adrian How did u edit the bold letter into grey highlights? Just curious, looks better too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two Things :

---

- First : Do not make query in loop !

---

- Second : you're in a before trigger, do not perform an update dml for the records in the trigger.new

---

And you have a mistake in your code i think : if(go.Ship_To__c=='') should be if(go.Ship_To__c!='')

I definitive, your code should be

```
trigger updateAccountName on orders__c (before insert, before update) {

    Map<String,SUBSCR_SYSTEMS__c> partnerAcc =new Map<String,SUBSCR_SYSTEMS__c>();
    Set<String> shipTo = new Set<String>();
    List<orders__c> orders = new List<orders__c>();

    for(orders__c go: Trigger.new)
    {
        if(go.Ship_To__c!=''){
            shipTo.add(go.Ship_To__c);
            orders.add(go);
        }
    }

    for(SUBSCR_SYSTEMS__c s:[select Account__c from SUBSCR_SYSTEMS__c where LEGACY_CUST_NUM__c IN: shipTo])
        partnerAcc.put(s.LEGACY_CUST_NUM__c,s)

    for(orders__c go: orders)
        if(partnerAcc.containsKey(go.Ship_To__c)
            go.account__c=partnerAcc.get(go.Ship_To__c).Account__c;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! My sql query will return only 1 value so I kept in loop. You are correct about the condition too. I remove that! I get this error on trying your suggestion... Error: Compile Error: Variable does not exist: go.Ship_To__c

Comment: Your query get only one record by order no ? So if you have 200 orders record (batch, dataloader...) you will perform 200 SOQL queries witch is very bad ! That's why we move the query outside loops

Comment: I have make some edit in my code maybe you have copy/paste before that. Your error is on the SOQL query on SUBSCR_SYSTEMS__c  object ? I had left a mistake in the query

Comment: Hi I tried and error pointed to the SOQL with ERROR as Execution Of BeforeUpdate Caused By: System.QueryException: Non-selective Query Against Large Object Type...

Comment: Could you try to define the LEGACY_CUST_NUM__c  as External Id ? I think this will index the field. That's the problem when using a IN parameter with String list i think

Comment: Hi @Yann. It's working. Thanks! Kindly explain me about changing the field into an external id.

Comment: External Id allow you to use this field in upsert call, instead using the salesforce Id in lookup fields. When the field is flag as external Id, i think salesforce create a database index on this field.

Comment: Thanks :). Don't forget to mark you question as answered :)

Comment: hey Yann! I update from workbench, the trigger works fine. But when I go to the detail page and update I'm asked to select the account lookup value also. Why is that?

Comment: Does the Account field marked as required in the page layout ?

Comment: Hi @yann thanks for your help. I would like to know 1 more thing.Can this code handle more than 10k records?

Comment: The SOQL select Account__c from SUBSCR_SYSTEMS__c where LEGACY_CUST_NUM__c IN: shipTo doesn't work if I have large values.  
I feel it's not bulkified even though we are adding it to collections in loop instead of using DML in loops. But when I mass update for the field "Ship_To__c" for the trigger to work, I get too many queries ERROR from that SOQL Where do you think I should make changes in order to bulkify? Sorry this question is not related to the above questions.

Comment: It's strange because the code is in bulk mode. I don't often work with collection of String in SOQL query but the error message is very strange. You shouldn't have it. Do you have another trigger on your orders__c object ?

Comment: No trigger, checked thoroughly. Let me do a little more research on this. But the error only from arises the soql :(

Comment: :(. Account__c field is a master-detail to Account object ? If yes, do you have roll-up summary field and trigger on Account ? If yes to all these questions, update the Account__c field will change Roll-up on Account object, which perform an update and fire trigger. So maybe some soql query on these trigger